# WCF Rest Service, Request Handling

Tags: wcf, rest, wcf-data-services, wcf-binding

I have a WCF service using `webHTTPBinding`. The service can be consumed by a client using some C# program or JavaScript.

The service is running fine and also working exactly I wanted. One of the method in service looks like

```
public string JSONGetSomedata(List<MyCustomObject> item)
{
    // some code here, which is working fine....
}
```

When this service is accessed using a client or JavaScript, It works fine provided that I'm passing passing data to method as expected.

Now, The case where I'm consuming mentioned service using JavaScript, if I pass `nothing or pass item=123` then request does not reach to WCF method at all. And it throws error like

[image: Error that I'm receiving for service.]

Is there any way by which I can return some friendly error or other Json/XML data...?

I'm not sure how to do it...

**Note here that, I'm looking for solution on how to return Json/HTML instead of this error message.**